# call http-webpage in local browser, where the webserver is only reachable through proxychains (as it sits in a different network)

Tags: burp-suite, proxychains, pivoting

I have the following proxychains.conf

```
[...]
[ProxyList]
# add proxy here ...
# meanwile
# defaults set to "tor"
#socks4         127.0.0.1 9050

# <ip_prox_1>
http 10.10.10.100 3128

# the loopback interface of ip_prox_1
http 127.0.0.1 3128

# <ip_prox_2>
http 10.20.20.100 3128
[...]
```

Now I call proxychains and wget on the terminal to get the webpage (which is working)

```
# proxychains wget 10.20.20.101
```

How do I have to configure my machine, so that I can view this website, that is hosted in the internal network on 10.20.20.101, with my webbrowser (running as user and not as root), starting from the same network as the ip_prox_1 machine?

I tried it with burpsuite, but there is no option like chaining proxies...

Comment: Have you tried simply running the web browser under proxychains?  It should work out of the box.